# Firebase Timestamp (serverValue) in seconds?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

### **1. The problem**

I'm trying to write some values organizing them by the timestamp value (in seconds, not milliseconds) they arrive to the database in order to trigger a function in the server every time data arrives.

I expect to register this every second because milliseconds will trigger too many times and I don't need it that often.

E.g.

```
|- timestampSecond1: true
|- timestampSecond2: true
|- ...
|- timestampSecondX: true
```

*I'm using Firebase Realtime Database*

### **2. What I've tried**

**2.1. ServerValue Timestamp:**
Using this approach writes the timestamp in milliseconds. Since ServerValue Timestamp is a placeholder that gets replaced directly by the server the moment it arrives, I cannot modify it before it gets replaced or when I sent the post request to the server in order to convert it to seconds.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue

**2.2. Cloud Functions:** Phased server function to evaluate and calculate the range to the millisecond written by ServerValue and then writing in another branch the value in seconds.

**2.3. Cloud Functions:** Function triggered by the arrival of data and writing the data in seconds directly. Calculating internally the equivalence in seconds of the timestamp.

*I'm aware 2.2. and 2.3. will work for what I'm trying to do, but I'm wondering if there is another way to do this without envolving server functions.*

### **3. Help**

Are there any workarounds to mark the timestamp in seconds using ServerValue or other methods that ensure the timestamp written is the same data arrives to the server?

Thank you.

Comment: The question is a bit vague - we don't know how you are writing the data to the server nor what's preventing data to be written as seconds. Can you clarify the question? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks. I thought ServerValue Timestamp (point 2.1) was precise enough to explain the issue since it's a built-in property in all Firebase SDKs. When used, you send a 'placeholder' to Firebase and it is the server that replaces it with its own internal timestamp when the data arrives (not when it is sent). As told, since this placeholder triggers an internal Firebase function, it can't be modified unless you use a function that overwrites it (2.2. & 2.3) - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue . I'll add this info to the question.

Comment: I am familiar with the server timestamp. As I mentioned we don't know how you're writing data - e.g. we don't know what you're doing to trigger the write or how frequently it's done. Are you using an external cron job? Are you levering the Firebase automated functions? etc. What's the problem with just writing them from the client app? That's the vague part - what code isn't working?